# how to get data of SellerCloud in php Soap

Tags: php, web-services, soap

how to get data of SellerCloud using Soap 1.1 in php, this is the link: http://tt.ws.sellercloud.com/scservice.asmx?op=Orders_GetDatas

here is the End Point Details : https://www.programmableweb.com/api/sellercloud | SellerCloud API

Here is API documentation of SellerCloud : http://developer.sellercloud.com/article/OoZlmewSpM-orders-get-datas

```
$wsdlurl = "http://tt.ws.sellercloud.com/scservice.asmx?WSDL";
$apiauth =array('UserName'=>'username','Password'=>'password', 'ApplicationVersion' => '5642', 'ApplicationVersion' => 'Testingname');
$header = new SoapHeader('http://api.sellercloud.com/', 'AuthHeader', $apiauth);
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdlurl)
$soap->__setLocation('http://tt.ws.sellercloud.com/scservice.asmx?WSDL');
$soap->__setSoapHeaders($header);       

$params = array('orderIds'=> 5222241);
$soap->__soapCall("Orders_GetDatas", $params);
```

Comment: No RESTful API? No PHP SDK? What is this 2004? Getting any errors back? Getting enough insight? If not then be sure to assign "exceptions" => 0  and "trace" => 1. Then check `__getLastRequest` / [`__getLastRequestHeaders`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) for clues.

Comment: Also, per those docs, "orderIds is an integer array". Maybe `$params = ['orderIds'=> [5222241]];`

Comment: hello @ficuscr i am using php but its not working. and its says "you no has Device Id Validator "  ... check is link of SOAP http://tt.ws.sellercloud.com/scservice.asmx?WSDL .. and my function is orders_GetDatas

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out.  Definitely not intuitive.  Be sure to replace the three pieces of data that are specific to your account.

Obviously, this is just one function, but it shows how the parameters need to be formatted.

```
<?
$wsdl = "http://[[server prefix]].ws.sellercloud.com/scservice.asmx?WSDL";
$namespace = "http://api.sellercloud.com/";

$sc = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    "trace" => 1, 
    "exception" => 1
));
$apiauth = array(
    'UserName' => "[[username]]", 
    'Password' => "[[password]]",
    'ValidateDeviceID' => false
);
$header = array();
$header[] = new SoapHeader($namespace, 'AuthHeader', $apiauth, false);
$header[] = new SoapHeader($namespace, 'ServiceOptions');
$header[] = new SoapHeader($namespace, 'SerializableDictionaryOfStringString');
$sc->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$params = array(
    'Filters' => array(
        'Keys' => array('UseSP', 'DateFrom', 'DateTo'),
        'Values' => array('GET', '07-01-2018 00:00:00', '07-01-2018 00:11:00')
    )
);

try {
    $response = $sc->Orders_Get($params);
    var_dump($response);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage() . "\n"; exit();
}
?>
```